# Do we have another expression that is similar to "Speaking of Which" which is very confusing?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I heard many American people say "**Speaking of Which...**"

According Urban Dictionary
"**speaking of which**" means "**by the way**"

Do we have another expression that is similar to "**Speaking of Which**" which is very confusing?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for, an expression that means "very confusing”?

Comment: Urban Dictionary is not a reliable dictionary.

Comment: It is **most definitely** not just American English. Please be more careful with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Speaking of which' is a way of introducing a new topic **connected with** the topic previously being discussed or mentioned:

> Person A: I have a new camera.
> Person B: Speaking of which, my
> camera is broken.

[Speaking of someone or something (Cambridge Dictoonary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speaking-of-someone-something)

'By the way' is a way of introducing a new topic **not** connected with the topic previously being discussed.

> Person A: Look at my new hat!
> Person B: Oh, that's nice. I like the
> style. By the way, my sister is moving to Australia.

[By the way (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by-the-way)

They don't mean the same.

Comment: Of course I understand "Speaking of your birthday/ job/..." but not "Speaking of which". What does "which" refer to? Your answer has not said what "which" here means?

Comment: @Tom 'Which' can be used as a pronoun used to refer to something just mentioned. Also you can use 'whom' if it is a person. Person A: My mother does not like football. Person B: Speaking of whom, how is her new puppy?

Comment: So, it roughly mean, "Speaking of which you are talking about" and "Speaking of whom you are talking about" right?

Comment: Speaking of [the subject] which we have just been discussing...